# How to create lists from every item of an existing list in python 2.7.11?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to generate lists from the elements of a list in python.
For example: there is a list with the following information: 
 `list=['AB4', 'AB3','AC3', 'BC4', 'BC5']` 
This is the exact format of the elements of the list. 
I suppouse to create list for every element, separate for the letters (considering both letters as one block) and separate for the numbers, that will contain the missing character from their string. Here is what I mean:

```
 AB:['4', '3']
 AC:['3']
 BC:['4', '5']
 4:['AB', 'BC']
 3:['AB', 'AC']
 5:['BC']
```

These are the lists that I should generate from the original list. There is no limitation to the elements of the original list, and their format is exactly like in the example "two letters and a number".

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: Does your input always consist of *3* characters, or can the numeric portion be longer?

Comment: You first need to loop through every value of your array. For every value check if you already have a list for it. If not create one, if yes then add the value to the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it:

```
from collections import defaultdict
l=['AB4', 'AB3','AC3', 'BC4', 'BC5']
result=defaultdict(list)
for item in l:  
    #If you want numbers to be numbers and not strings replace item[2:] with int(item[2:])  
    result[item[:2]].append(item[2:])
    result[item[2:]].append(item[:2])
```

And you can use this to print it just as you want:

```
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()
pp.pprint(result)
```

output:

```
{'3': ['AB', 'AC'],
 '4': ['AB', 'BC'],
 '5': ['BC'],
 'AB': ['4', '3'],
 'AC': ['3'],
 'BC': ['4', '5']}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves my problem. Is there any way that the answer is listed vertical instead of horizontally? I mean all the items in the 'result' to be displayed in a new line?Thank you again.

Comment: Do you mean when you print `result` after execution? If so, yes. I updated my answer.

Comment: Using `defaultdict(list)` will eliminate the need for `try except`

Comment: Or use `dict.setdefault(key, []).append(...)`.

Comment: I remodified the code as you. Than I got error at defaultdict, but after I imported it from collection the error was gone. But now my output is like this: defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'AC': ['3'], 'AB': ['4', '3'], 'BC': ['4', '5'], '3': ['AB', 'AC'], '5': ['BC'], '4': ['AB', 'BC']})

Comment: "import pprint
from collections import defaultdict

l=['AB4', 'AB3','AC3', 'BC4', 'BC5']

result=defaultdict(list)

for item in l:
    result[item[:2]].append(item[2:])
    result[item[2:]].append(item[:2])

pp=pprint.PrettyPrinter()
pp.pprint(result)"   What is wrong with my code that I do not have the same output as yours? I use python 2.7.11.

Comment: Yeah, that's the code. Which output do you get? Do you mean `result` is printed in different order? Bytheway I am using Python 3, but honestly I don't know to what extent that matters here.

Comment: Thank you @hipoglucido. It was because I was using python 2. Thus for python 2 the only modification is in this line: pp.pprint(dict(sorted(result.items()))).  With this change in the code I have the same output as yours but in python 2. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use regexes (the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module) and a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to accomplish this. The following will work for arbitrary lengths of the non-digit/digit parts of your input strings:

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

def str_dig(s):  # str_dig('ABC345') -> ('ABC', '345')
    return re.match('([^\d]+)(\d+)', s).groups()

lst=['AB4', 'AB3','AC3', 'BC4', 'BC5']  # do NOT shadow list!

d = defaultdict(list)
for x, y in map(str_dig, lst):  # map applies the str_dig function to all in lst
    d[x].append(y)
    d[y].append(x)

# d['AB']: ['4', '3'], d['3']: ['AB', 'AC']
```

Comment: Great. Much better than my answer. You earned my upvote:-)

Answer (score 2):

How about this,

```
import itertools
import operator

l = ['AB4', 'AB3','AC3', 'BC4', 'BC5']
lists = [(s[:2], s[2]) for s in l]      # [('AB', '4'), ('AB', '3'), ('AC', '3'), ('BC', '4'), ('BC', '5')]

results = dict()

for name, group in itertools.groupby(sorted(lists, key=operator.itemgetter(0)), key=operator.itemgetter(0)):
    results[name] = map(operator.itemgetter(1), group)

for name, group in itertools.groupby(sorted(lists, key=operator.itemgetter(1)), key=operator.itemgetter(1)):
    results[name] = map(operator.itemgetter(0), group)

print(results)
# Output
{   'AC': ['3'], 
    'AB': ['4', '3'], 
    'BC': ['4', '5'], 
    '3':  ['AB', 'AC'], 
    '5':  ['BC'], 
    '4':  ['AB', 'BC']}
```